# Java Web Start update file another path/local

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a question concerning the Java Web Start update jar files!

My scenario is the following:

I have a local and off line java application, and it's works fine with JWS, like JNLP file below:

```xml
 <jnlp  
    spec="6.0+"  
    codebase="file:/D:/eclipse_juno/workspace/"  
    href="desktop.jnlp">  
    <information>  
        <title>My Program v1.0</title>  
        <offline-allowed/>  
    </information>  
    <security>  
        <all-permissions/>  
    </security>  
    <update check="always" policy="always"/>
    <resources> 
        <jar href="desktop.jar" main="true"/> 
    </resources>  
    <application-desc main-class="AppDesktop"/>
</jnlp>
```

But, this application can only be called locally. 
So when is an improvement in the application, we make available this jar file in the network as: \servername\appjar\jarfile.jar!

I can make the application to run from a local computer and check for updates on a file server?
Obviously this will occur when the computer connects to a network

Any ideas? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your "codebase" is set to "file:/D:/eclipse_juno/workspace/" so even if you enable auto-update it will check to see if there is an update available at "file:/D:/eclipse_juno/workspace/". I assume you want the update to be somewhere on the web, so no you cannot set the codebase to be local and still receive update from the web.

I suggest to change the codebase to point to http://www.yourdomain.com/yourapp/ but keep the  in there so that the first time the user runs the jnlp it needs to access the internet to download jar files but after that it won't need internet and can use the local cache until internet connection becomes available again.